# How do I use Microsoft's Git-TF 1.0 when TFS is not on-premises

Tags: git, tfs, git-tf

Following the post
 [Using Git in a TFS shop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687883/using-git-in-a-tfs-shop),
Reading Brian Harry's blog on msdn:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2012/08/13/announcing-git-integration-with-tfs.aspx and
Having gone through Ms download page:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30474,

It was not clear to me whether I can use Git-TF 1.0 with a TFS which is not on my premises but accessible via VPN.
I am open to a work-around in-case its impossible right now; it should allow me to work independently within a team and not get dependent on some other member to push my Git stuff to the TFS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr:**  Yes, it should work, I use it over a PPTP VPN daily (and it's rare that I'm ever *not* on the VPN.)

To explain what was meant in that blog post:  the Team Foundation Server team makes a distinction between our "hosted" or "cloud" service ([Team Foundation Service](http://tfspreview.com)) and our "on-premises" product (the Team Foundation Server you install on your own computer.)  We use the term "on-premises" to mean the TFS 2012 you install even if it's not on your local network, or even in your own data center.

If you're curious, the problem was around authentication - git-tf has no UI and thus can't open up a web browser to require your authentication on [tfspreview.com](http://tfspreview.com).  We needed to add support to the Team Foundation Service to allow other credentials.

This has been done and [git-tf can now authenticate to the hosted service](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2012/08/13/announcing-git-integration-with-tfs.aspx).

If you have problems, please raise an issue on [the git-tf codeplex site](http://gittf.codeplex.com/).

Comment: thanks @Edward for the much needed clarification of 'on-premises'. I will check this out.

Comment: I use git-tf on my VPN all the time now.

Answer (score 0):

From the 2nd link:

> ...it will only work with an on premises TFS server – either 2008,
>   2010 or 2012. However we are working on adding support for Team
>   Foundation Service and I expect it will be available in the next
>   sprint deployment.

Sounds like you might have to wait for the next version or play around with the [source](http://gittf.codeplex.com/)

Comment: This was particular to Team Foundation Service (tfspreview.com) and not for users who VPN into their work network.  In addition, Team Foundation Service added the necessary support for this: http://tfspreview.com/en-us/learn/code/use-git-and-vs-with-tfs/