# Git and TFS integration for TFS Build

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2012

I have situation in which I need to use:

- Git as a main repository for my source
- Visual Studio 2012 main IDE
- TFS Build on Build machine for easier build management

Well, I am after Git and TFS integration in which I ideally want a seamless check in into the Git repository which should result in a CI build in the TFS build.

Guy, any ideas to how to achieve this?

Comment: A GIT hook calling a script to start TFS? -- http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-3.html

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a duplicate of

[Using Git in a TFS shop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687883/using-git-in-a-tfs-shop?rq=1)
and
[Git and Team Foundation Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614245/git-and-team-foundation-server)

both of which suggest using https://github.com/spraints/git-tfs to tie your git repo to your TFS server. You should be able to use git as your source control and TFS Server as a build controller.

Answer (score 3):

My job has found great success with [git-tf](http://gittf.codeplex.com/) as a way to integrate git and TFS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TFS GIT repository for your GIT  required projects.
If it is only required for Building a project, you can look for Jenkins or Latest TFS. As Latest TFS does provide Jenkins inbuilt.