# Local git repository on Local TFS 2012

Tags: git

Microsoft has [introduced](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/01/30/git-init-vs.aspx) git support for [Team Foundation Service](http://tfs.visualstudio.com).

Is it possible to use Git on an On-Premise Team Foundation Server 2012 instance?

Comment: Try researching this a little. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1687883/291641 for a local link or search google for git-tfs and git-tf.

Comment: this is not what I want! this is using git (third party) and syncing it to tfs. What I want is: Microsoft has introduced git support on Visual studio 2012 Update 2 and TFS2012 services (which are cloud tfs services). So Is it possible to use LOCAL (non cloud) TFS 2012 git repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be available in [TFS 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/06/03/visual-studio-2013.aspx).

<strike>From Brian Harry's [Blog Post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/01/30/git-init-vs.aspx) on the subject:</strike>

Under the heading **When is it shipping?**

> Team Foundation Server – Our plan is to include Git support in the
>   next major release of TFS.  No date has yet been announced.

Comment: So no git support jet :-(. Thanks for the info.