# Team Foundation Server 2012 and GIT

Tags: git, tfs

Is it possible to build projects created in vs2012, manually pushed to my git repository with Team Foundation Server 2010/12?

In the other words: Can I choose my git repository path as source, to build it with TFS?
I've chosen TFVC as source control because TFS2012 doesn't support git as source control yet.
I know I can do this in Team Foundation Service but I don't want to use it.

Comment: Are you talking about the hosted service at visualstudio.com, or a local installation of TFS? how does GIT come into this?

Comment: My TFS is on-premise for example on Computer A. I want TFS to manage(build etc.) my git source control which is also on the Computer A.

Answer (score 7):

It should be possible now, keep in mind as well that the Update 2 for VS 2012 added GIT support.Take a look: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GitSupportForVisualStudioGitTFSAndVSPutIntoContext.aspx

> You can use VS Git support with all your Git projects by just opening
>   projects. It's just Git. I am pushing branches to CodePlex, to GitHub
>   and other Git repos. I'm also continuing to use my other Git tools
>   interchangeably, as I like.
>
> For teams, you can go up to http://tfs.visualstudio.com and sign up
>   for a account and get 5 users for free. You can choose either Git or
>   Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC) as the source provider and use
>   all the Team Foundation agile, scrum or other templates for your ALM
>   tools.