# How to rebase in TFS using TFVC? (like git rebase functionality)

Tags: version-control, merge, rebase, tfs-2015

Using tfs2015 (not git but tfvc)

We have a MAIN branch and I created my development branch from MAIN branch.

```
__MAIN (branch)
  |__MYDEV (my new branch)
```

After a while, my friends pushed 2 new changesets to MAIN.

```
__MAIN [change1], [change2]
  |__MYDEV [mychange1]
```

**Question:** How can I get those 2 changesets onto MYDEV branch as 2 changesets as they are by merging (rebasing) my change on their changes?

If I try merging MAIN onto MYDEV, 2 changesets are coming as pending changes of bunch of files, but I want them as they are as packaged in 2 changesets and put my changes on them.

Finally what I expect,

```
__MAIN [change1], [change2]
  |__MYDEV [change1], [change2], [mychange1-with-merge-fixes]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use [git-tfs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2239653/23118) it will give you all the powers of git, highly recommended. Now, visual studio will maybe be a little bit upset when it detects a `.git` directory, but you can avoid that by setting GIT_DIR and GIT_WORK_TREE environmental variables (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25977667/23118) for details).

Answer (score -3):

You can use "Rebase" tool to keep every merged changeset separately in the branch.

To use rebase tool in TFS, follow the steps below if you have Team Explorer installed:

1. Launch Team Explorer and connect to your project.
2. Open "Branches".
3. Checkout the branch (MYDEV) you'd like to rebase.
4. Right click the branch and select "Rebase Onto..." option.
5. Select the Onto Branch (MAIN) and then click "Rebase" button. (Resolve the conflict and click "Continue" button if there is any conflict during the rebasing)

Introduction about TFS Rebase:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Code/git/rebase

Comment: thanks for your help, but I can not see the "Branches" in team explorer, do you have any idea?

Comment: I tried on source control explorer, by right clicking on my branch but there is no "Rebase onto .." option.

Comment: well, you're talking about git, we are using tfs unfortunately for source control

Comment: TFS2015 support two version control: TFVC and Git, do you mean you are using the TFVC version control?

Comment: yes, I m not talking about git, it is totally VisualStudio, Team foundation server and its fracking source control tool (TFVC).

Comment: TFVC does not support the "rebase" feature.